# Узнать, изменилось ли поле при изменении элемента?

Tags: битрикс

В обработчике события обновления элемента(OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate), как узнать, изменено ли поле и какие поля вообще изменились?

или как получить поля ДО изменения, чтобы можно было сравнить

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно провести операции до изменения элемента, то вам необходимо использовать событие `OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate`.

Вот пример использования. Деактивирование разделов в процессе импорта

```
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockSectionUpdate","DeactivateImportSections");
function DeactivateImportSections(&$arFields)
{
    if (($arFields['IBLOCK_ID'] == 21) && ($_REQUEST['mode'] == 'import')) {
        if ($arFields["ID"] == 451 or $arFields["ID"] == 452 or $arFields["ID"] == 453) {
            unset($arFields["ACTIVE"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я уже решил.